# M2M authentication on exposed java ee rest endpoints

Tags: java, rest, security, encryption

I have to design and implement a java EE application that has to be able to communicate with other applications.
By communicate, I mean applications send me sensitive data and I send back other sensitive data so I have to encrypt and decrypt all the data traveling on the internet.

Let me show you a little example:

My server has an external endpoint: @POST ../userData

This endpoint is called by many applications. It provides all the data about a user.

I have to go for sure, that the application, that asks this information is authorised to get this data.

**My question**: What is a good practice to identify, if the application, that asks for informations from my app using my exposed rest endpoints, is an authenticated app.

If he correct way is encrypting the data with a key, how can I give the right key to the other application.

If I am in the dark about this all, please show me the way I should design this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do something like this, at a device level rather than an application level, for an IoT device is to use a public/private key pair.

There is a lot of good information on the concepts online - you will get to hear a lot about 'Bob' and 'Alice' and their secret message exchanges: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

For IoT devices, the private key is installed or configured on the device and is uniquely associated with that device.

The public key allows the server or controlling side to verify messages from that IoT device, signed with its private key, are really from that device.

There are quite a few services that will allow you manage keys and certificates or IoT devices, including from Google and AWS:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/understanding-the-aws-iot-security-model/
- https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/keys

For your use case, especially if your application is the only one on the device and tied to the device, then it may be easiest to leverage a device key like the above.

If you are not able to leverage a unique device ID then you typically will want to implement the same type of Public Private key pair in your application itself.

The private key in this case will be associated with the application and will be distributed with the application. To avoid attackers reverse engineering the private key it is usually hidden using some form of obfuscation or 'white box' cryptography.